# what does と in the sentence below mean?

Tags: grammar

> そんな彼らは、仕事を頼まれてもすぐに始めることができない。失敗したくないので、仕事をする前にいろいろ質問をしてくる。彼らの気持ちがわからないと、聞かれた人は自分の若い時と比べて仕事に消極的だ、ロばかりで働くのを嫌がる、**と**誤解することになる。

does this "と" mean "and" and is used to connect 嫌がる and 誤解する?

or does this と mean "that" and is used to quote the content before it?I mean the sentence "聞かれた人は自分の若い時と比べて仕事に消極的だ、ロばかりで働くのを嫌がる" is the content of "と誤解する"

Answer (score 2):

It's quotative, so your second interpretation is correct. But the content is 自分の若い時...嫌がる.

The subject of 彼らの気持ちがわからない as well as 誤解する is 聞かれた人.

Thus a literal translation would be

- When they (asked) fail to understand what they (askers) think, they (asked) misunderstand that they (askers) are passive in work compared with people of their (asked) age *and that* they (askers) just chat and dislike working.

As a side note, *and that* above does not exist in the Japanese sentence. The structure is: X, Yと誤解する=misunderstand that X and that Y.

Comment: thank your explanation,your explanation is well articulate